# Replace the javascript code in html by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the javascript code in html by javascript

So I am testing like this.

```
var test = new String("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> test </script>");

test.replace(/<script type=\"text\/javascript\">.+<\/script>/g,"");
//this doesn't match

console.log(test.toString());
```

test.replace doesn't match and console.log shows this.(nothing happens!)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> test </script>
```

Is there any mistake??

Comment: `.replace` **returns** a new string. But the more important question is, why are doing this? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: An aside not an answer, but you don't need `new String()` or `.toString()` there - every string in JS is an object of type string.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you need to do this.

Comment: @IMSoP: Well, not quite. Most are string primitives. Using `new String` is a terribly bad idea. Anyways, whitebear: why’re you trying to do this? It doesn’t seem like a good idea somehow.

Comment: @IMSoP: Technically no. There are string *primitives* and string *objects* and they behave slightly differently. You should never use `new String` thought, because it makes things very confusing.

Comment: Also using </script> inside Javascript will end the Javascript... Use something like "</scr" + "ipt>" to avoid the HTML parser seeing </script> (even though it's inside quotes)

Comment: Your approach is not a good one, regular expressions should not be used for matching markup (since HTML is not a regular language).

Comment: @Felis Kling thanks.... I am ashmed... :-(

Comment: @pscs: It could be external JavaScript.

Comment: I made you confused sorry. honestly I am not using javascript but titanium. it uses javascript but not on browser.

Comment: @whitebear - **Never** use primitive constructor in JavaScript. They will return incorrect values, for example, while `false` is false, `new Boolean(false)` is true.

Comment: @pscs—that does absolutely nothing of any value. A closing tag is denoted by `</`, the rest is just for convenience. To property quote a closing script tag, use `<\/script>`.

Comment: @minitech and FelixKling: I stand corrected; I will have to read up on that distinction some time. JS is so much more intricate than it seems on the surface!

Comment: The constructor functions for primitives can be useful without `new`. But I guess then they're not technically a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.replace` returns the replaced string, it does not replace `test` in place.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace